# How to dependency inject interface in angular 6 unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

One of the service dependency injects an interface in the constructor. I wonder, how I can dependency injects the interface in the unit test?

Exported interface:

```
export interface MobilePlatform {
  onClick(): void;
  onPageFinished(router: Router): void;
  onPageStart(): void;
  sendClose(): void;
  tts(text: String): void;
}
```

Service injects the interface in the constructor

```
constructor(private platform: MobilePlatform, private router: Router) {}
```

How I can inject this interface in the angular unit test?

```
describe('MobileActions', () => {
  let actions: MobileActions;
  let platform: MobilePlatform;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MobileActions,
        { provide: MobilePlatform, useClass: MockMobilePlatform },
        { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }
      ]
    });

    actions = TestBed.get(MobileActions);
    platform = TestBed.get(MockMobilePlatform);
  });

  it('should create actions', () => {
    expect(actions).toBeTruthy();
    expect(platform).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Seems this kind of inject failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, since an interface is a contract that does not get transpiled to an actual class function. In order to create a testable representation of such interface in the Angular injector, you will want to create a typed injection token:

Somewhere in your MobilePlatform models file:

`export const MOBILE_PLATFORM = new InjectionToken<MobilePlatform>('mobilePlatform');`

Then in your service constructor:

`constructor(
  @Inject(MOBILE_PLATFORM) private platform: MobilePlatform,
  private router: Router
) {}`

Finally, in the `providers` array of your testing module:

`{ provide: MOBILE_PLATFORM, useClass: MockMobilePlatform },`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, help me a lot. I think I make some mistake here. I should write the unit test for a class instead of service. So I may need to give up the TestBed here.

Comment: Hi @pablo I am following same pattern and working perfectly. The problem is not I want to spy if the method from MockMobilePlatform has been called or not when some method is executed in MobileActions spec file. (which is basically injecting that mobileplatform)

Comment: Keep in mind that providing in modules like this is not tree-shakeable. That may or may not be something to be concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't achieve this using TestBed, instead I use mock classes like this

```js
class MobilePlatformMockClass implements MobilePlatform {
    // implement interface mock functions
}

describe('MobileActions', () => {
  let actions: MobileActions;
  let platform: MobilePlatform;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mobilePlatformMock = new MobilePlatformMockClass();
    const routerMock = { navigate: () => {} };
    actions = new MobileActions(mobilePlatformMock, routerMock)
  });

  it('should create actions', () => {
    expect(actions).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```